# How to dynamically select child dropdown depending on parent dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been struggling to get this to work but no success. Researched many tutorials and videos but still not working.

I have a Region Table in my DB with `region_id(PK)` and `region_name` as columns.
I also Center Table with `center_id(PK)`, `center_name` and `region_id(FK)`

`region_id` is foreign key on center table

I have the register.php file that fetches the datafrom DB and Ajax.php

It's only the select dropdown of region that's working. The Centers under the selected region will not display in the Center Select dropdown.

Register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/soap/includes/server.php';
?>

<html>
<body>
<div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Region 
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate 
 = "Region is required">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>

                    <select class='input100' name='region'>
                    <option value disabled selected>Select 
Region</option>
                        <?php  
                            $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 
region");
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                                {
                            echo '<option 
value="'.$row['region_id'].'">'.$row['region_name'].'</option>';
                                } 
                        ?>
                    </select>


                </div>

                <br>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $regionError;?></span>


                <div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Center 
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate 
= "Center is required">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    <select class='input100' name='center'>

                                <option value="">Select Center</option>
                    </select>
                <script 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function()
                            {
                        $(".region").change(function()
                            {
                        var region_id=$(this).val();
                        var post_id = 'id='+ region_id;

                        $.ajax
                            ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax.php",
                            data: post_id,
                            cache: false,
                        success: function(centers)
                            {
                                $(".center").html(centers);
                            } 
                        });

                        });
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>

                <br>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $centerError;?></span>
```

Ajax.php

```
<?php
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/soap/includes/server.php';
   if($_POST['id']){
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   if($id==0){
       echo "<option>Select Center</option>";
   }else{
       $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM center WHERE 
       region_id='$id'");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<option 
    value="'.$row['center_id'].'">'.$row['center_name'].'</option>';
       }
    }
  }
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does select `.center` exist? I can only see select `.input100`, of which you have two. Try using an additional/alternative class selector for your ajax html result.

Comment: `$(".region").change` there is no element with class "region"

Comment: @JustBaron Thanks for your prompt response. This is my Select Center Field. What is wrong here? 
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = 
     "Center is required">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <select class='input100' name='center'>

                              <option value="">Select Center</option>
                        </select>

Comment: @LaoluAladejana See kerbholz's response. There isn't an element `.region`, so your ajax is not triggered. And there isn't a `.center` element for the result to be updated to. Check your console log.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys.

You pointed out my errors. I just added class='region' and 'center' to 'input100' classes on both select fields.

Thanks for helping me out. I appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

```
</script>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function()
                            {
                        $(".region").change(function()
                            {
                        var region_id=$(this).val();
                        var post_id =region_id;
                         var post_id=JSON.stringify(post_id);  

                        $.ajax
                            ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax.php",
                            data:{"id":post_id},
                            cache: false,
                        success: function(centers)
                            {   
                                var centers=JSON.parse(centers);  
                                $(".center").html(centers);
                            } 
                        });

                        });
                        });
    </script>
```